# Opening a zip file in C++ with XZIP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In my current project, I have to go to a certain user inputted directory, open that directory and read all the zip files in that directory which begin with W. I am trying to use the XZIP library for opening the ZIP files, but I am certainly doing something very wrong. I am confused whether to use UnzipItem or Openzip to open the zip file and parse through its contents. (The zip files each contain some .jpg files and I have to copy those files into another location, but that's the second part of the project)

I would really appreciate some help, Thanks :)

Here is my code-

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "src\XZip.h"
#include "src\XUnzip.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "src\dirent.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main()
{

  std::ifstream fin;
  std::string dir, filepath;
  int num;
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *dirp;
  struct stat filestat;
  std::string filename;
  std::string userInput;
  std::cout << " Input dir to get files from : ";
  getline( std::cin, dir );  // gets everything the user 
  dp = opendir( dir.c_str() );
  if (dp == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening " << dir << std::endl;
    }
  char test[2];
  while ((dirp = readdir( dp )) != NULL)
    {  // printf(" inside the directory ");
        filepath = dir+"/" + dirp->d_name;
        filename =dirp->d_name;
        test[0]=filename[0];
        test[1]='\0';
        if ( test[0]=='W')
        {   HZIP* z;
            DWORD File_name = std::strtoul(filename.c_str(), NULL, 16);
            OpenZip(z,0,File_name);


        }

  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the help that is delivered with the library?

Comment: Yes I did read that, but I couldn't find any good examples of how to actually use those functions. I am open to using something else, but I felt that XZIP was something simple enough to try.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4135/XZip-and-XUnzip-Add-zip-and-or-unzip-to-your-app-w) I'd say that you first need to call `OpenZip` to get a  handle back and with that handle call `UzipItem` with an item id you got from `FindZipItem`.

All i have is the documentation:

> flags  - indicates usage, see below;  for files, this will be                       ZIP_FILENAME

So i guess something like: `auto handle = OpenZip("file.zip", 0, ZIP_FILENAME);`

Comment: That was my idea too...but do you know how to call it, I dont think I am calling it correctly in my program. The third argument of OpenZip, the DWORD argument is confusing me. Hence could you show me how to call it, with respect to my program. Thanks.

Comment: Well that doesnt really tell me what to do...but thanks anyway